# SAS date subtraction when intck function doesn't cut it

Tags: date, sas, formats

I need to do some date subtraction in my SAS code, but I don't think the INTCK function will work because I would like the answer to present the difference in days:hours:minutes.  I could program this out, but I am guessing there is probably a format or function I'm not aware of to accomplish the task.

For example:

Date1 = 01JAN2000 12:00

Date2 = 02JAN2000 14:30

difference = 1:02:30 (i.e. 1 day, 2 hours, 30 minutes)

In this case, if I used INTCK I would need to keep the units in either days or hours, but I can't get the desired format above.

Comment: The difference between to datetime values represents the difference in seconds. It looks like you are just asking for a custom TIME format.

Comment: Yes, I think that is probably right.  I could not find a time format in the SAS documentation that gives days as well as hours and minutes.  Is there a  format for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `%n` directive in a PICTURE format.

```
proc format;
 picture pictdhmf
  low-high='%0n:%0H:%0M'(datatype=time)
 ;
run;
```

Note you need to use data type of TIME. **WARNING: It doesn't produce proper results when running SAS using DBCS support (for example using Shift-JIS encoding).  Or for times that are less than zero.**  It does work for non-negative values when using single byte character sets, even with UTF-8 encoding.

So instead you could build a function.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.func.func;
function dhmf(c) $;
  length f $ 10;
  f=catx(':',datepart(abs(c)),put(timepart(abs(c)),tod5.));
  if c < 0 then f='-'||f ;
  return (f);
endsub;
run;
options cmplib=work.func;
```

and then make a format that calls the function.

```
proc format;
value dhmf(default=10)
 other=[dhmf()];
run;
```

So if we test both methods and compare to the values that TIME format produces.

```
data _null_;
  input (date1 date2) (:datetime24.) ;
  diff = date2 - date1 ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'RAW' @11 'TIME.' @20 'Function' @ 30 'Picture';
  put diff comma9. @11 diff time. @20 diff dhmf. @30 diff pictdhmf.-l ;
cards ;
01JAN2000:02:30 02JAN2000:03:45
01JAN1960:08:00 01JAN1960:17:00
01FEB2017:00:00 04FEB2017:06:23
01FEB2015:00:00 04FEB2017:06:23
04FEB2017:00:00 01FEB2017:06:23
run;
```

We get:

```
 RAW       TIME.    Function  Picture
    90,900 25:15:00 1:01:15   1:01:15    
    32,400  9:00:00 0:09:00   0:09:00    
   282,180 78:23:00 3:06:23   3:06:23    
  63440580 17622:23 734:06:23 734:06:23  
  -236,220   -65:37 -2:17:37  -2:06:23
```

Comment: Ooh, `%n` is `datatype=time` - is that documented anywhere??

Comment: I contacted the Documentation team to see if they can modify the doc for that, since it's definitely not something I am aware of and doesn't seem documented anywhere...

Comment: Thank you! I had never heard of a picture format, so I've certainly learned something new.  One question.  In your example in the answer, your last row has a difference of 11 hours in the result for function vs. picture format and I don't understand why.  Can you explain?

Comment: The PICTURE format doesn't work right for negative times.  If you use it you can modify the ranges to have it output something if the value is <0. `picture pictdhmf  low-<0='negative' 0-high='%0n:%0H:%0M'(datatype=time);`
 ;

Comment: They got back to me and said they'd update the documentation.  Haven't seen evidence of said update so far but will check again in a bit.